# How to increase width of an input field?

Tags: css

I am trying to increase the width of an input field on [my website](http://rave.pk/).

This is how it looks

[image]

This is how I want it to look

[image]

But css fix is increasing its size. Please guide.

```
.searchform span .s {
padding: 6px;
width: 135px;
background: none;
float: left;
font: bold 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Increase the `width` in `span.near`.

```
span.near {
    width: 172px;
    background: url('images/nearbg.png') no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit this line of CSS:

```
span.near {
background: url("images/nearbg.png") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
width: 122px; <---INCREASE THIS
}
```

I think it is on line number 99 in your CSS file

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the width on `span.near`.

```
span.near {
    width: 189px;
}
```

Then you'll get the button outside the input. The 189px width is the maximum it can be set to before it breaks onto a new line

Answer (score -2):

You may write or define width as follow:-

```
 width: 135px !important;
```

OR you may add one more class like textWidth as follow:-

```
 .textWidth{
      width: 135px !important;

   }
```